# Uploading .mp3 files http error - 2 "exact" files one successful other fails

Tags: uploads, errors, media-library, http

I have 2 equal .mp3 files - technically different files but both exported from Audacity using the same settings and the same original audio. Exactly the same size, same content (albeit processed separately) - one fails and one succeeds.

Both files play fine but could some character in the file be tripping up the PHP upload?

I see this error - ap_pass_brigade failed - in the log from last week - GoDaddy takes a long time getting the logs saved and today's errors are nowhere. related?

```
[Tue Apr 26 20:34:35 2016] [9000082] [fcgid:warn] (32)Broken pipe: 
[client 173.160.120.186:51688] 
mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function, 
referer http://www.####.com/wp-admin/upload.php

[Thu Apr 28 12:56:54 2016] [9000082] [fcgid:warn] (110)Connection timed out:
[client 104.237.142.57:46250] 
mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function

[Sun May 01 12:29:20 2016] [9000082] [fcgid:warn] 
[client 104.236.68.137:58028] 
mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /web/cgi-bin/php-fcgi, 
referer http://####.com
```

[image]

I have the php memory settings and file uploads to 128mb and the timeout at 120seconds.

This one fails:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Byiy0gx4A9G-dFR3MjdlTjFZUDg

This one succeeds:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Byiy0gx4A9G-REhWVnRIMU5jek0

Running PHP 5.4 on GoDaddy

I have tried the 'fixes' for the imagick issue in PHP 4.5 to no avail.

my htaccess:

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php

SetEnv MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT 1

<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

# Exclude the file upload and WP CRON scripts from authentication
<FilesMatch "(async-upload\.php|wp-cron\.php|xmlrpc\.php)$">
    Satisfy Any
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Deny from none
</FilesMatch>

RewriteEngine On

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

GoDaddy's senior tech had no idea what was up - maybe a corrupted Wordpress? I did however do a refresh install and no change.

Comment: Are there any errors in the server logs?

Comment: Server log - rather delayed on GoDaddy - last week one upload looks like the server timed it out - I added notes above. 

I also see a possibly related error in the WP 4.5 core files [core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/36534] but this bug refers to images and imagick. Can't see that getting triggered by an .mp3 file but who knows. Host is on GoDaddy btw. –

Comment: I'm leaning towards godaddy as the issue. A fresh install of WP and new db upload fails. Same version of WP on a different host the file uploads fine. Maybe mod_security ?

Comment: Has anyone experienced this issue with mod sec?

Comment: On occasion I am able to upload mp3 file after re-exporting it from Audacity. I am experiencing exact same issue (Audacity and GoDaddy). I have been able to upload "bad" mp3 to WP library on a different host provider. Have you found a solution?

Comment: You are correct - the only workaround right now is to re-export the file and suddenly the server doesn't flag the file as an attack and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Same exact issue, some MP3 files upload fine, but others don't upload and the page timesout. If i re-save the file, 9 times out of 10 it will upload fine. No idea why some get flagged as bad files. Very simple PHP script uploading via move_uploaded_files or using a FTP both come out with the same issue. I've essentially given up the issue, if i get a bad file i either re-save or manually upload using an FTP program. If anyone has any answers to this problem please help it would save me so many hours trying to figure out why.